# gbm in R crashes

Tags: r, rstudio, gbm

I tried to use gbm(formula, data) in Rstudio on my dataset. But Rstudio crashes on windows and Mac without any message (just " Rstudio needs to restart"). Any idea how I can fix this issue?

thanks

Comment: Have you tried it in R without RStudio?

Comment: I get the same problem without R studio as well and I have sufficient memory on the machine.

Comment: How large is your dataset? How many predictors? Default parameters for interaction depth and max tree number?

Comment: There are only about 7000 rows and 13 features of which I am currently trying with one or two features. I have not used gbm before. The randomForest and other models work. I am having trouble with gbm. On windows, it crashes with Rstudio and R console (comes up with a windows firewall error). It crashes on Mac with Rstudio, but I got it to work with  R console on Mac. However, my predictions are all NaN. My predictors are just 2 numeric variables. My target variable is a factor.  I am just using the default: gbm_mod = gbm(target~Var1+Var2, data=train, distribution="bernoulli").

Answer (score 10):

I had that issue when my classification response was set to factor. Changing response to numeric resolved it.

Comment: This just solved a problem I have been having all day. Thanks!

Comment: This also resolved a mysterious gbm crash which failed in both R Gui and RStudio - thank you!